# Java send floatbuffer over a tcp socket efficiently

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, buffer

I am relatively new to socket programming in java and want to send data from a Floatbuffer variable over a tcp socket. This should run on an android platform.

Here's some code to illustrate what I want to do:

```java
FloatBuffer buf = FloatBuffer.allocate(4);
buf.put(5.5f);
buf.put(1.5f);
buf.put(2.5f);
buf.put(3.5f);

ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(38300);
con = server.accept();

// somehow send the whole buf variable over the tcp socket
```

I am sure you can extract each float and individually send them over the socket, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do so?

Comment: i don't see how you send your data - so it's very hard to tell what your problem with 'more efficient' is... can you detail your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a backing `ByteBuffer` for it. That way you have plenty of choices on how to transmit the data over the network. With a `SocketChannel` you'll get it as simple as this.

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(floats*4);
FloatBuffer floats = buf.asFloatBuffer();
floats.put(5.5f);
...
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(38300);
SocketChannel sc = server.accept().getChannel();
sc.write(buf);
```

Comment: I tried this out today, but I get the error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.write(java.nio.ByteBuffer)' on a null object reference

Comment: Sounds like your `ByteBuffer` is null. Did you follow this code exactly?

Comment: it's the sc object that is null, but got it to work following this example http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/server-socket-channel.html

Answer (score 1):

The most **efficient** solution **in terms of quantity of data sent over the network** is sending the float directly.

Every float is 32 bit lengths and is not possible to reduce it if you needs to send float.

An alternative, not always applicable, is to **send less bits using a different type**.

For example instead of sending

```
5.5f
1.5f
2.5f
3.5f
```

why don't multiply them by 10 and send only `byte` or `short` primitives?

On the other side of the socket you can reconstruct the float dividing the byte (or short) by 10.0

For this kind of solution **you can save 4x (for byte) or 2x (for short) in terms of bits sent over the network**.

**Note:** you can apply this solution **if you know that the range of possible data is restrict to same known values**. As an example sending values between 0 to 10 with 1 decimal digit.

Comment: What if he needs to send `5.57f` instead?

Comment: It is necessary to see the range of values of data to be sent. Sometimes passing from float to byte or from float to short is possible sometime not.

Comment: There is no best solution always applicable. It depends always on the kind of data. This is a possible solution that is applicable on the data of the example. If all the data are of this kind this a good possible solution, better then sending floats (in term of data sent over the network).

Comment: Rather than going for an ad-hoc solution proposed, a simple and general way (if really the network is a bottle neck) would be to compress the data before sending. There are potentially bigger data savings, and in the worst case scenario (completely random data), the resulting compressed data would not exceed the original data in any major way.

Comment: I repeat this is a solution for the problem exposed. Sending four floats in a particular range. If this is not the case other possible ways can be taken. But if this scenario is a good representative of the existing scenario this solution is better then others. As additional note compressing few random floats is not efficient in terms of data sent over network and also in terms of cpu usage.

Comment: This is my last comment, but do you really think the question was about sending 4 floats over the network in the most efficient manner? If you need to send 4 floats, it doesn't matter what way you send them, they will all fit in a single TCP packet.